# How do I get the glass cover off of a shower light?

Tags: lighting, shower

I have a recessed shower light in my shower with a burned out light bulb that needs to be changed. The glass cover screws into the metal flashing and is sealed with a cork gasket.

[image: Recessed Shower image]

However, I cannot turn or twist it off. I have tried to pull the flashing off, but I do not want to damage it. It looks like it may be secured from the inside and accessible when the glass cover is off.

[image: Shower light closeup]

I would greatly appreciate any ideas or helpful ideas to remove this. I have also tried using a rubber mat for extra grip, but that wasn't enough either.

Comment: Rather than the mat, you might try some dipped gloves, such as [these](http://www.marks.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/marks-marksdefaultsalescatalog/workwear/work-gloves/dakota-2-pack-lite-pu-coated-53768).  Having the rubber around your fingers will give you better grip than the mat.

Comment: Are you sure the trim doesn't screw off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been painted, and badly at that, which is going to make everything stick together. Get a utility knife and score around the edge of the flashing, a.k.a the baffle, and see if it will come off after that. Modern day recessed light baffles are held in place by three metal tabs that push on the side of the can. They are like springs. When I take my down to replace the bulb it feels like I"m going to pull the whole thing out of the ceiling. The thing has a death grip on the can. Could be similar with yours, in which case the flashing will pull straight down. On my cans I had to use a metal L shaped [dental pick](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001LJGMXI) to get under the lip of the can so I could get my fingers under it and start pulling.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, it was way to painted over to pull down, but a pick-like tool really helped.